# firebase.auth().currentUser returning an object with undefined properties? Reactjs

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

here is my code:

```
const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

function submitPostHandler() {
    if (user) {
        const currentUser = auth.currentUser;
        firestore.collection("posts").add({
            title: title,
            desc: desc,
            imgUrl: imgUrl,
            poster: currentUser.displayName,
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
            comments: []
        });
        console.log(currentUser);
        //navigate("/all-posts");
    }
    else {
        navigate("/login");
    }
}
```

Simple, whenever I run this function it logs an object that has properties that are undefined as in if I switch `console.log(currentUser);` with `console.log(currentUser.displayName)` it logs undefined. Unusually `useAuthState();` returns true.

It seems like when I was creating the user with the `createUserWithEmailAndPassowrdOrSomething()` I was not passing in the email and password. I forgot to change this when @Dharmaraj told me before.

Comment: Default value of `displayName` is indeed undefined. Do you set this property when a new user registers?

Comment: Don't forget to also store `uid: currentUser.uid`. A user's display name is likely to change, but their UID won't.

Comment: @Dharmaraj - When the user logs in with google it has a set display name but when they login with the email and password method i set the display name to their specified display name so it should be defined. samthecodingman - I am defining the user that posted the post so I don't see how I would be able to get the user's display name using the uid.

Comment: I said don't forget to *also* store their user ID. Display names are not unique and can be changed by the user whereas the user ID will always be the same for that user. Storing the user ID in each post makes moderation much easier and helps with any GDPR-related requirements. You can keep adding the poster as you are here, but if that user changes their display name, how are you going to keep track of their posts, comments, stats, spam, abuse, user blocklists, etc. and how do you know which posts to update their display name on?